# Filter significant hits out of big dataset with row and column name

Tags: r, unix, grep, filtering

What I have is a few big files like this one;

```
IID     geneA           geneA1          geneA2          geneA3          geneA4
snp24   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116
snp25   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116
snp26   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116
snp27   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116
snp28   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116
snp29   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    2.0107465936227367e-11  0.0009575306    0.9999998116
snp30   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    4.033923217176159e-11   0.04319423  0.9999998116
snp31   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    7.983277836657833e-11   0.0933816338    0.9999998116
snp32   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.0018850954    0.4196570142    0.9999998116
snp33   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.6007038997    0.9999998116    0.9999998116
snp34   0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116    0.9999998116
```

and I need to filter out the highly significant ones. Now at first I taught this would be easy with `grep "e-"` but then I get the whole row.

What I would like to get out of these files is something like this (all highly significant hits):

```
snp29  geneA2   2.0107465936227367e-11
snp30  geneA2   2.0107465936227367e-11
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How do you define "all highly significant hits"? Min/max...?

Comment: Everything lower than e-8

Comment: @FlorisBrenk, you may find [MatrixEQTL](http://www.bios.unc.edu/research/genomic_software/Matrix_eQTL/) package useful for your analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach will do the job (`dat` is the name of your data frame):

```
sig <- 1e-8  # the threshold

idx <- which(dat[-1] < sig, arr.ind = TRUE)

res <- data.frame(ID = dat[idx[, "row"], 1],
                  gene = names(dat)[-1][idx[, "col"]],
                  sig = dat[-1][idx])
```

The result:

```
     ID   gene          sig
1 snp29 geneA2 2.010747e-11
2 snp30 geneA2 4.033923e-11
3 snp31 geneA2 7.983278e-11
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use R, here is a simple solution.  First you can filter the dataset using grep like this:

```
grep e datafile > filtered.out
```

This will choose rows with significant data so you don't need to read it all into R, as well as the header (which contains an 'e').  Then in R you can run this:

```
data <- read.table("filtered.out",T,row.names=1)
sig <- data< 1e-8
sigvalues <- data.frame(IID=rownames(data)[row(data)[sig]],gene=colnames(data)[col(data[sig]],value=data[sig])
```

Here's the output:

```
    IID   gene        value
1 snp29 geneA2 2.010747e-11
2 snp30 geneA2 4.033923e-11
3 snp31 geneA2 7.983278e-11
```

There's probably an all-unix way to do this also, but I'm not enough of unix expert to come up with it offhand.  But I see that fedorqui has figured it out using awk.